# Why can't I play competitive matches on CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-family-sharing

I am playing CS:GO through a family shared library. I can play online *casual* matches and bot matches however I can't play competitive matches through my account. However, if I login to my brother's account (he's the one who bought the game), I can play competitive matches. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't"? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe only offline play is supported for a shared copy of CS:GO.

> http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3206227

Trying to find an official statement from Valve, but the link above has users talking about this exact situation.

Comment: Yup, that's the issue. Just an FYI for anyone looking, this *only* applies to CS:GO Competitive matches - no other games (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

You can't play CS GO online it will just keep loading for years if you waited that long. You have to buy your own copy of the game. Either you can just play with bots or buy the game.